# Finding Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

> Find the Euler-Lagrange equation for $\int_0^4(tx'-(x')^2)dt$.

My attempt:
$0 - \frac{d}{dt}(t-2x')=0$

From here, I am not sure what to do. Quite frankly, I don't even think I started the problem correctly. Any hints to guide me into the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. From what you got $$-\frac{d}{dt}(t-2x^\prime)=0$$, we obtain $$\boxed{1-2x^{\prime\prime}=0}.$$ This is the answer for your question. On the other hand, if you want to solve the differential equation, it is better integrating $-\frac{d}{dt}(t-2x^\prime)=0$ to obtain $t-2x^\prime=C_1$, where $C_1$ is a constant. Integrating one more time, we get the solution $$x(t)=\frac{t}{2}\left(\frac{t}{2}-C_1\right)+C_2,$$ where $C_2$ is another constant.

Comment: Oh so that IS what I do - thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Isi I edited my answer. Could you check my answer again?

Comment: I see - I am slightly confused by the latter half of your answer. Could you perhaps explain where this constant came from, or why it is better to integrate?

Comment: The answer to you question is $\boxed{1-2x^{\prime\prime}=0}$. On the other hand, if you want to solve the differential equation $1-2x^{\prime\prime}=0$ to get its solution, it is better to integrate $\frac{d}{dt}(t-2x^\prime)=0$ twice, as I did in my answer. The constants of integration appear because the solution of the differential equation depends on the initial conditions.